# I cannot create file with php-fpm nginx with user apache in my directory 777

Tags: php, nginx

it is my php code

```
echo getcwd();
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', true);
file_put_contents("t.txt","asdasd");
echo exec('whoami');
```

and show me

```
/var/www/test3
Warning: file_put_contents(t.txt): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/test3/index.php on line 5
apache
```

and

ls -lav /var/www/test3

> .. drwxr-xr-x. 8 apache apache  87 Jul 18 05:12
>
> -rwxrwxrwx. 1 apache apache 165 Jul 18 06:58 index.php

Comment: What does `getcwd()` return?

Comment: my current path.it is true

Comment: my problem is from SELinux.I turn off that and resolved it.sudo setenforce 0